# Error allocating file install folder in WIX 3.9

Tags: directory, wix, windows-installer

I am setting up the installation locations for my installer. However, it throws an error when I try to set the locations. Source code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="Wix_setup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Frank Jansen" UpgradeCode="37a42e55-dea8-47da-8f4f-fb065dd38a9e">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Wix_setup" Level="1">
      <!--create a seperate ComponentGroupRef and Fragment for each extra added program-->
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="InstallationFiles" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="DLLs" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="IniFiles" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Scripts" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="TeamViewer" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Wix_database" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Wix_setup" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" ></Property>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>

    <ComponentGroup Id="DLLs" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

      <Component Id="cmp0F2CCC19DBBB1A659BB614D21AAFB413" Guid="{1B34DA48-A891-4923-8437-8116FB986A4E}">
        <File Id="filFD63715191DEBF4B34A2836B7D53C62B" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Users\fjansen\Documents\MMI installatie bestanden\MMI install files\Program Files\ActiveX Control Pad\ScrWiz.dll" />
      </Component>

    </ComponentGroup>

      <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" />
      </Directory>

  </Fragment>
```

What I am trying to do in this example is placing a file in the program files folder. But when I build the solution it throws the following errors:

```
Error   3   Duplicate symbol 'Directory:ProgramFilesFolder' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated. Check to make sure all your identifiers of a given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique.

Error   1   Duplicate symbol 'Directory:TARGETDIR' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated. Check to make sure all your identifiers of a given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique.
```

I don't understand why I get these errors. I need to define multiple pads to multiple locations and some parts of those pads are the same as other ones, which means that, for example, I need to use ProgramFilesFolder multiple times for different files. But now I get an error when I do that.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This structure should help you.
Reference the id of CommonFilesFolder

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Wix_setup" />
        <Directory Id="CommonFilesFolder" />            
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

this link might help you in future

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2esdf4x%28VS.80%29.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_folder_properties)

Comment: Thanks, I already saved that link for reference. I figured it out just before I did read your post how to add Common files folder. I am going to perform some tests with this piece of code and check how you can for example reach sub folders in Common Files, since that didn't work out up to this point. Is it good practice to make a fragment for each structure to a certain map / location or should I put everything together in one fragment?

Comment: using fragments is good practice.But you must also keep this fragment in separate files to make maximum use of it.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I need to add an installer file for every fragment? bud do i have to make a reference from  those file to Product.wxs ( main file )?

Answer (score 0):

You cant repeat ids for directories.
Try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="Wix_setup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Frank Jansen" UpgradeCode="37a42e55-dea8-47da-8f4f-fb065dd38a9e">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Wix_setup" Level="1">
      <!--create a seperate ComponentGroupRef and Fragment for each extra added program-->
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="InstallationFiles" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="DLLs" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="IniFiles" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Scripts" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="TeamViewer" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Wix_database" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Wix_setup" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" ></Property>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="DLLs" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="cmp0F2CCC19DBBB1A659BB614D21AAFB413" Guid="{PUT-GUID-HERE}">
        <File Id="filFD63715191DEBF4B34A2836B7D53C62B" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Users\fjansen\Documents\MMI installatie bestanden\MMI install files\Program Files\ActiveX Control Pad\ScrWiz.dll" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>      
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, this part I got working now. However how can I set a sub directory? for example: ProgramFilesFolder\Common Files. i tried it with <Directory Id="Common Files>" underneat the line of the <ComponentGroup Id> bud what ever I try it just does not accept it.